# Gnuplot: triangle in log-log axes

Tags: gnuplot

I want to plot a right triangle with hypothenuse parallel to the slope of a curve in loglog scale. However, gnuplot behaves funky:

```
set terminal postscript eps enhanced "Helvetica" 22

a1 = 64459.7;
a2 = -1.90748;

func(x) = a1*x**a2 

X1 = 1e+4;
Y1 = 1e-4;
X2 = 2e+4;
Y2 = Y1 + func(X1) - func(X2)

set logscale xy
set format x "10^{%T}"
set format y "10^{%T}"
set key top right 
set output 'temp.eps'

set object 1 poly from X1,Y1 to X2,Y1 to X1,Y2 to X1,Y1 fs empty border 1
set xrange [0.8e+4:1e+5]

plot func(x) title sprintf("a line with slope %1.2f",a2)

unset object 1
```

and outputs
[image]

Perhaps in log-log scale the command `set object` behaves differently when in `log-log` scale, otherwise i have no idea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the right answer is:

`Y2 = Y1 * 10**(a2 * log10(X1 / X2) );`

p.s. moderators, feel free to delete the question

Comment: Why should a moderator delete your question?

Comment: because i think it's trivial